# Qt - change the text of QTextBrowser inside GridLayout

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit, qtwidgets

I've got a `QGridLayout` filled with `QTextBrowser's`.

I am getting access to them using `itemAtPosition(i,j)`, so I can eg. change to background using `widget()->setStyleSheet`.

Is there any way to **change the text** inside those fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setText() or append() to do this, but your way to get pointer is not very good. You should operate with original pointer. For example

```
QTextBrowser txt;
grid.addWidget(&txt,...);
//...
txt.append("example");//we just use object, we don't get this object from layout
```

QTextBrowser inherits QWidget, so you can use setStyleSheet() too.

About your current approach: of course you can cast your pointer to needed type using qobject_cast but try to use easier approach.

```
(qobject_cast<QTextBrowser*>(grid.itemAtPosition(0,0)->widget()))->append("example");//is it so beautiful?
```